# How to get the country, province information from PostGIS given latitude and longitude

Tags: postgis

The project requires us to be able to pin point which state the given geographic coordinate belongs to. These points need not be only in the US.

One possible idea we had was to use PostGIS.

Is it possible to configure PostGIS to give us back such information?

I had a look at http://postgis.net/docs/Reverse_Geocode.html. It seems like it is possible to Reverse Geocode with this, but what we want is slighly different. We want to be able to store all provincial data and be able to tell which **country + province** the point corresponds to, if any.

How can we achieve this?

We would rather want to have an in house solution than depending on a third party solution like Google API as we need to be able to process a lot of rows of data. Google etc, have a lot of limitations on usage.

Answer (score 4):

You should try https://gis.stackexchange.com/, I'm sure this question has been asked before, but to save you some time here it goes: reverse_geocode may work the way you want to, but you need the data first, so the real question is where to get the geometries from all the countries and its sub-divisions, you can get them here: http://www.gadm.org/ , but this is a shapefile, so you need to use `shp2pgsql`.

The syntax for `shp2pgsql` is this:

> shp2pgsql -s 4326 gadm_v2.shp new_table_name > new_table_name.sql

And then you can use reverse_geocode.